# How can I convert matlab code to image?

Tags: matlab

For exmaple,I have the following code.

```
% Generate random data from a uniform distribution
% and calculate the mean. Plot the data and the mean.

n = 50;            % 50 data points
r = rand(n,1);
plot(r)

% Draw a line from (0,m) to (n,m)
m = mean(r);
hold on
plot([0,n],[m,m])
hold off
title('Mean of Random Uniform Data')

for v = 1.0:-0.2:0.0
  disp(v)
end
```

I want to convert MATLAB code to an image.

For example, if you copy the MATLAB code into a software then it return the image like this：

[image]

How to do it?

> If I use this code and publish it to PDF file,the code is not completely display.

```
sumLumi(x,y)=LLmap3(floor(x/4)+1,floor(y/4)+1)+LLmap3(floor(x/4)+2,floor(y/4)+1)+LLmap3(floor(x/4)+1,floor(y/4)+2)+LLmap3(floor(x/4)+2,floor(y/4)+2);
```

[image: Use the <code>SnapShot</code>,you can copy the whole page into Clipboard]

Comment: You can break a line and continue in MATLAB by using `...`, see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MATLAB editor you can Publish your document as a PDF (by changing the Output file format to pdf under publishing options). It will also evaluate the code unless you change the *Publishing Options>Code Settings>Evaluate code* to `false`.

The PDF can then can converted to an image (a quick google search gives an online PDF to JPG converter).

You can break a line and continue on the next with `...`, for example

```
sumLumi(x,y)=LLmap3(floor(x/4)+1,floor(y/4)+1)+LLmap3(floor(x/4)+2,floor(y/4)+1)+LLmap3(floor(x/4)+1,floor(y/4)+2)+LLmap3(floor(x/4)+2,floor(y/4)+2);
```

can be written as

```
sumLumi(x,y) = LLmap3(floor(x/4)+1, floor(y/4)+1) ...
               + LLmap3(floor(x/4)+2, floor(y/4)+1) ...
               + LLmap3(floor(x/4)+1, floor(y/4)+2) ...
               + LLmap3(floor(x/4)+2, floor(y/4)+2);
```

Comment: If one have Acrobat, not Reader, *File>Export>Image>...* tool can be used.

Comment: If one use `Foxit Reader`, push `SnapShot` button can copy page into Clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Matlab only you can use this workflow:

1. Make your code to be single `.m` file. Any text file will work.
2. Read this file in `cell` column vector `Code`;
3. Process the lines adding using `TeX` or `LaTeX` formatting commands;
4. Create white figure with `text(x,y,Code)`;
5. Export the figure.

This might be good way to produce many figures with same style.